# Local Storage Only Storing Part Of My data And Nothing is being stored in Session Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a student and I am building a website for a course. This is the js, html, and css pages in the website. When I run this program, it saves the street address in local storage but not the city and zip code. I can not figure out why this is happening. Nothing is showing up in the Session Storage at all. I have attached the app.js, html-template.js, menu.js, app.css and submit.html. I have attached a screen shot of the browser debugger of what is being put in local storage.

```js
**APP.JS**


var App = {

  Menu: null,
  OrderCostTotal: 0,
  PendingOrderKey: "PendingOrder",
  UsedAddressesKey: "UsedAddresses",
  DeliveryAddressKey: "DeliveryAddress",
  AddressIDSelected: null,
  RefreshCycle: 4000,
  OrderStatus: ["Canceled", "Order Placed", "We Are Preparing Your Food", "In The Oven / Cooking", "Out For Delivery"],


  Init: function() {


    this.Menu = JoesPizza.Menu;
    $("#PizzaOrderNext").click(this.OrderNext);

  },

  InitSubmit: function() {

    this.LoadOrderDetails();
    this.LoadOrderAddress();

  },

  LoadMenu: function() {

    $("#MenuItemList").html("");

    this.Menu.items.forEach(item => {
      let html = HtmlCode.GetMenuItem(item);
      $("#MenuItemList").append(html);


    });

    // attach click events to new menu items
    let selector = "div[act=\"add2order\"]";
    $(selector).click(function() {
      //read values from the clicked menu item
      let lbl = $(this).attr("lbl");
      let cost = $(this).attr("cost");
      App.OrderCostTotal += parseFloat(cost);
      // html order item
      let html = HtmlCode.GetOrderItem({
        "lbl": lbl,
        "cost": cost
      });
      $("#PizzaOrderItems").append(html);
      App.OnAddUpdateOrderTotal();
      // attach click events on order items
      // add remove method; this can be improved
      $(".order-item").off("click");
      $(".order-item").click(function() {
        let cost = $(this).attr("cost");
        App.OrderCostTotal -= parseFloat(cost);
        App.OnRemoveUpdateOrderTotal();
        $(this).remove();
      });
    });
  },

  OnAddUpdateOrderTotal: function() {

    // needs correction
    let selector = '#PizzaOrderSummary, #PizzaOrderNext';
    $(selector).css("visibility", "visible");
    let total = "$" + App.OrderCostTotal.toFixed(2);
    selector = "#PizzaOrderSummary > div:nth-child(2)";
    $(selector).html(total);
  },

  OnRemoveUpdateOrderTotal: function(cost) {

    // needs correction
    if ($(".order-item").length == 1) {
      let selector = "#PizzaOrderSummary, #PizzaOrderNext";
      $(selector).css("visibility", "hidden");
      return false;
    } else {
      let total = "$" + App.OrderCostTotal.toFixed(2);
      let selector = "#PizzaOrderSummary > div:nth-child(2)";
      $(selector).html(total);
      return true;
    }
  },

  OrderNext: function() {

    if ($(".order-item").length == 0) {
      alert("There seems to be a problem with your order.");
      return false;
    }

    // read order info
    let arr = [];
    var total = 0;
    $(".order-item").each((idx, item) => {
      let lbl = $(item).attr("lbl");
      let cost = $(item).attr("cost");
      arr.push({
        "lbl": lbl,
        "cost": cost
      });
    });

    // store order into
    let json = JSON.stringify(arr);
    localStorage.setItem(App.PendingOrderKey, json);

    // move to submit page
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
    window.location.assign("/submit/");

  },

  LoadOrderDetails: function() {

    let buff = localStorage.getItem(App.PendingOrderKey);
    let order = JSON.parse(buff);

    order.forEach(item => {
      App.OrderCostTotal += parseFloat(item.cost);
      let html = HtmlCode.GetOrderDetailsItem(item);
      $("#OrderDetails").append(html);
    });

    let data = {
      "lbl": "Total Cost:",
      "cost": App.OrderCostTotal.toFixed(2)
    };
    let html = HtmlCode.GetOrderDetailsItem(data);
    $("#OrderDetails").append(html);
  },

  LoadOrderAddress: function() {

    let buff = localStorage.getItem(App.UsedAddressesKey);
    if (buff == null) {
      let html = "<div>Enter address to deliver your pizza</div>";
      $("#AddressSelect").html(html);
    } else {
      let adrs = JSON.parse(buff);
      let html = HtmlCode.GetAddressSelector("SelDelAdr", adrs);
      $("#AddressSelect").html(html);
      /* attach events */
      $("#SelDelAdr").change(function() {
        App.AddressIDSelected = parseInt($(this).val());
        let adr = adrs[App.AddressIDSelected];
        $("#txtStreetAddress").val(adr.street);
        $("#txtCity").val(adr.city);
        $("#txtZipCode").val(adr.zcode);

      });
    }

    let selector = ".address-lines > div:last-child";
    $(selector).click(App.PrePostOrder);
  },

  PrePostOrder: function() {

    /* read address info */
    let street = $("#txtStreetAddress").val();
    let city = $("txtCity").val();
    let zcode = $("txtZipCode").val();

    /* homework... validate address info */
    if (!App.validateAddressData(street, city, zcode)) {
      alert("Please correct address info.");
      return false;
    }

    /* create and store delivery address */
    let adr = {
      "street": street,
      "city": city,
      "zcode": zcode
    };
    localStorage.setItem(App.DeliveryAddressKey, JSON.stringify(adr));

    /* cache address */
    App.CacheCurrentAddress(adr);

    /*
    here we are ready to submit our pizza order to joe's pizzeria
    we hide current frame and bring up status frame
    http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/
    */

    $(".submit-delivery").fadeOut(500, () => {
      $(".submit-status").fadeIn(500, () => {
        App.PostOrder();
      })
    });

  },

  CacheCurrentAddress: function(adr) {

    if (App.AddressIDSelected != null)
      return false;

    let buff = localStorage.getItem(App.UsedAddressesKey);
    let arr = (buff) ? JSON.parse(buff) : [];
    if (App.IsAddressCached(arr, adr))
      return false;

    arr.push(adr);
    buff = JSON.stringify(arr);
    localStorage.setItem(App.UsedAddressesKey, buff);

  },

  IsAddressCached: function(arr, adr) {

    let rval = false;
    let street = adr.street.trim();

    for (let idx in arr) {
      let buff = arr[idx].street.trim();
      if (buff === street) {
        rval = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    return rval;
  },

  validateAddressData: function(street, city, zcode) {

    let rval = true;
    /*
        check if passed values are null, undefined or empty strings
        if so reject... return false;

        rval = false
    */
    /* if (street !== "" && city !== "" && zcode !== null){
         return rval;
     } else {
         rval = false;

     */
    return rval;
    /*   }
     */
  },

  PostOrder: function() {

    /*alert("posting order"); */
    let order = localStorage.getItem(App.PendingOrderKey);
    let addr = localStorage.getItem(App.DeliveryAddressKey);

    /* place order */
    let backend = new ClientBackend();
    backend.PostOrder(order, addr, (msg) => {

      let orderid = parseInt(msg);
      if (orderid) {
        $("#feedbackMsg").html(`Your Order ID: ${orderid}`);
        /* start to monitor order status */
        setInterval(App.MonitorOrderStatus, App.RefreshCycle, orderid);

      } else {
        $("#feedbackMsg").html(msg);
      }

    });

  },

  MonitorOrderStatus: function(orderid) {

    let backend = new ClientBackend();
    backend.MonitorOrderStatus(orderid, (scode) => {
      let status = App.OrderStatus[parseInt(scode)];
      let dts = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
      let msg = `Your Order ID: ${orderid}; <i>${status};</i> ${dts}`;
      $("#feedbackMsg").html(msg);

    });
  }

}

function newFunction() {
  return "SelDelAdr";
}


**HTML-TEMPLATE.JS**  


var HtmlCode = {

  GetMenuItem: function(item) {

    let plg = item.choices[0];
    let prg = item.choices[1];
    let lbl_plg = `${item.type} - ${item.name} - ${plg.size}`;
    let lbl_prg = `${item.type} - ${item.name} - ${prg.size}`;

    return `<div class= "menu-item"> 
        <div><div><img src="${item.img}"></div><div>${item.name}</div> 
        </div><div>${item.descr}</div> 
        <div> 
            <div act="add2order" id="${plg.id}" cost="${plg.cost}" lbl="${lbl_plg}" title="Click to order">${plg.txt}</div> 
            <div act="add2order" id="${prg.id}" cost="${prg.cost}" lbl="${lbl_prg}" title="Click to order">${prg.txt}</div> 
            </div> 
            </div>`;

  },

  GetOrderItem: function(item) {

    return `<div class="order-item" cost="${item.cost}" lbl="${item.lbl}" 
            title="Click to remove">
            <div>${item.lbl}</div><div>$${item.cost}</div></div>`;
  },

  GetOderItem: function(item) {

    return `<div class="order-item" cost="${item.cost}" lbl="${item.lbl}" 
            title="Click to remove">
            <div>${item.lbl}</div><div>$${item.cost}</div></div>`;
  },

  GetOrderDetailsItem: function(item) {

    return `<div class="sd-item-details"><div>${item.lbl}</div>
            <div>$${item.cost}</div></div>`;
  },

  GetAddressSelector: function(id, adrs) {

    let buff = "<option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\">--- Select Address ---</option>";
    adrs.forEach((adr, idx) => {
      buff += `<option value="${idx}">${adr.street}</option>`;
    });

    return `<select id="${id}">${buff}</select>`;
  },

}

**MENU.JS**


var JoesPizza = JoesPizza || {};

JoesPizza.Menu = {
  "items": [

    {
      "type": "Pizza",
      "name": "Cheese",
      "descr": "Marinara sauce topped with whole milk mozzarella cheese.",
      "choices": [{
          "id": "pizza-cheese-lg",
          "size": "Large",
          "cost": 22.99,
          "txt": "Large: $22.99"
        },
        {
          "id": "pizza-cheese-rg",
          "size": "Regular",
          "cost": 18.99,
          "txt": "Regular: $18.99"
        }
      ],
      "img": "/imgs/cheese.png"
    },

    {
      "type": "Pizza",
      "name": "Pepperoni",
      "descr": "Marinara sauce with authentic old-world style pepperoni.",
      "choices": [{
          "id": "pepp-lg",
          "size": "Large",
          "cost": 23.99,
          "txt": "Large: $23.99"
        },
        {
          "id": "pepp-rg",
          "size": "Regular",
          "cost": 19.99,
          "txt": "Regular: $19.99"
        }
      ],
      "img": "/imgs/pepperoni.png"
    },

    {
      "type": "Pizza",
      "name": "Meat Lover's",
      "descr": "Marinara sauce, authentic pepperoni, natural Italian sausage, roasted ham, smoked bacon, pork and beef.",
      "choices": [{
          "id": "meat-lg",
          "size": "Large",
          "cost": 23.99,
          "txt": "Large: $23.99"
        },
        {
          "id": "meat-rg",
          "size": "Regular",
          "cost": 19.99,
          "txt": "Regular: $19.99"
        }
      ],
      "img": "/imgs/meat.png"
    },

    {
      "type": "Pizza",
      "name": "Supreme",
      "descr": "Marinara sauce, pepperoni, pork, beef,fresh mushrooms, fresh green bell peppers and fresh red onions.",
      "choices": [{
          "id": "supr-lg",
          "size": "Large",
          "cost": 23.99,
          "txt": "Large: $23.99"
        },
        {
          "id": "supr-rg",
          "size": "Regular",
          "cost": 19.99,
          "txt": "Regular: $19.99"
        }
      ],
      "img": "/imgs/supreme.png"
    },

    {
      "type": "Wings",
      "name": "Traditional Bone-in",
      "descr": "Classic, juicy bone-in wings served perfectly crispy and tossed in your choice of signature sauce.",
      "choices": [{
          "id": "wings-trad-12",
          "size": "12 Pieces",
          "cost": 11.99,
          "txt": "12 Wings: $11.99"
        },
        {
          "id": "wings-trad-08",
          "size": "8 Pieces",
          "cost": 8.99,
          "txt": "8 Wings: $8.99"
        }
      ],
      "img": "/imgs/wings.png"
    }

  ]
};
```

```css
**APP.CSS**

.page-top {
  width: 98%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 2px;
  height: 64px;
  line-height: 64px;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border: 2px solid darkgrey;
  border-radius: 32px;
  /* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient */
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, green, white, red);
}

.page-top>img:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 24px;
}

.page-top>a {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 24px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.page-body {
  width: 96%;
  max-width: 1160px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 8px;
  height: auto;
  border: 0px dotted blue;
}


/*
    order.html
*/

.side-left,
.side-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
}


/* left side of the page */

#PizzaMenu {
  height: 480px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#PizzaOrder {
  height: 480px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#PizzaMenu>legend,
#PizzaOrder>legend {
  font-size: 24px;
}


/*
    tell students to group classes next to each other for a given topic
*/

.menu-item {
  border: 2px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.menu-item>div:nth-child(1) {
  height: 64px;
  line-height: 64px;
  border: 1px dotted transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 16px;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.menu-item>div:nth-child(1)>div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.menu-item>div:nth-child(1)>div>img {
  height: inherit;
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.menu-item>div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 96%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px dotted transparent;
}

.menu-item>div:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
}

.menu-item>div:nth-child(3)>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px 16px 4px 0px;
}

.menu-item>div:nth-child(3)>div:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}


/* right side of the page */

#PizzaOrderSummary {
  width: 80%;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #aab7b8;
  border-radius: 16px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#PizzaOrderSummary>div:nth-child(1) {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  text-indent: 12px;
}

#PizzaOrderSummary>div:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: right;
}


/* right side */

#PizzaOrderNext {
  width: 60%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #aab7b8;
  border-radius: 16px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#PizzaOrderNext:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.order-item {
  width: 98%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 4px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #aab7b8;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.order-item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f9b2b2;
}

.order-item>div:nth-child(1) {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
  text-indent: 12px;
}

.order-item>div:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16%;
  margin-right: 8px;
  text-align: right;
}


/*
    submit.html
*/

.submit-delivery {
  border: 2px solid #aab7b8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 520px;
}

.submit-status {
  display: none;
  border: 2px solid #aab7b8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 520px;
}

.sd-order-details,
.sd-address {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  border: 0px solid #aab7b8;
  margin-left: 5px;
  height: 520px;
  vertical-align: top;
}


/*
.sd-address {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%; 
    height: 520px;
    border: 0px solid #aab7b8;
    margin-left: 5px; 
    
}
*/

.sd-order-details>fieldset,
.sd-address>fieldset {
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.sd-order-details legend,
.sd-address legend {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-left: 14px;
}

.sd-item-details {
  width: 98%;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #aab7b8;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.sd-item-details>div:nth-child(1) {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75%;
  text-indent: 8px;
}

.sd-item-details>div:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22%;
  text-align: right;
}

.sd-item-details:last-child {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 16px;
}


/* Address Lines */

.address-lines {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.address-lines>div {
  width: 96%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 12px;
  height: 64px;
  border: 1px solid #aab7b8;
  border-radius: 32px;
}

.address-lines>div:last-child {
  width: 96%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 24px;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #aab7b8;
  border-radius: 24px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.address-lines>div:last-child:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.address-lines>div>div {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.address-lines input[type=text] {
  width: 88%;
  margin-left: 5.5%;
}

.address-lines label {
  margin-left: 6%;
}

#AddressSelect {
  line-height: 64px;
  font-size: 24px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
}

#AddressSelect>div {
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 88.5%;
  margin-left: 5.5%;
  text-align: center;
}

#AddressSelect>select {
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 88.5%;
  margin-left: 5.5%;
}

#feedbackMsg {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 96px;
  line-height: 96px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  border: 2px solid #aab7b8;
  border-radius: 32px;
  margin-top: 128px;
}

#feedbackMsg i {
  color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
**SUBMIT.HTML**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF8" />
  <title>Joe's Pizza</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/html-templates.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/clt-backend.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- top banner -->
  <div class="page-top">
    <img src="/imgs/pizza.png" title="Pizza Picture" />
    <span>joe's pizza</span>
    <a href="/">
      <img src="/imgs/home.png"></a>
    <a href="/orders/">
      <img src="/imgs/order.png"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="page-body">

    <!-- submit delivery html frame -->
    <div class="submit-delivery">
      <div class="sd-order-details">
        <fieldset style="overflow-y:scroll;">
          <legend>order details</legend>
          <!-- correct id in js code -->
          <div id="OrderDetails">
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div class="sd-address">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>delivery address</legend>
          <div id="DeliveryAddress">
            <div class="address-lines">
              <div>
                <div id="AddressSelect">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <label for="txtStreetAddress">enter street address</label>
                  <input type="text" id="txtStreetAddress" placeholder="exp: 8012 Austin Street" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <label for="txtCity">enter city, state</label>
                  <input type="text" id="txtCity" placeholder="exp: Queens, NY" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <label for="txtZipCode">enter zip code</label>
                  <input type="text" id="txtZipCode" placeholder="exp: 11415" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- get pizza button -->
              <div id="btnDeliver">Click To Get Pizza</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="submit-status">
      <div id="feedbackMsg"></div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    App.InitSubmit();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[BrowserDebuggerLocalStorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjWKA.png)

Comment: It's really hard to think through so much code. It would be great if you could minimize the code as much as possible. Often problems solve themselves when you go through that process.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to think exactly what the community would need out of the code that I have written without being confused,  while still being able to connect all the dots.

Comment: Thank you MyiEye for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I did. let city = $("txtCity").val(); let zcode = $("txtZipCode").val(); It should have a # in the "txtCity" and "txtZipCode" this code is found app.js.

App.js code:

PrePostOrder: function() {

```
/* read address info */
let street = $("#txtStreetAddress").val();
let city = $("txtCity").val();
let zcode = $("txtZipCode").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the values in a string format in the localstorage as

```
// store order into
let json = JSON.stringify(arr);
localStorage.setItem(App.PendingOrderKey, json);
```

So while parsing it, you have to convert it back to JSON object so that you could use its attributes.

You are getting it as

```
let buff = localStorage.getItem(App.PendingOrderKey);
```

Which should be

```
let buff = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(App.PendingOrderKey));
```

It will convert the stringified object to JSON Object.

Comment: The order details did not carry over and the address selector disappeared.

Comment: I noticed on the screen shot I posted the DeliveryAddressKey is missing [ ], but the other two keys have the [ ].

Comment: Hello, I figured out what I did. let city = $("txtCity").val();
    let zcode = $("txtZipCode").val();
It should have a # in the "txtCity" and "txtZipCode" this code is found app.js.

Comment: Thank you suzan for your answer.